# VBA: Concatenate values from WS Range to ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

On my Spreadsheets I have Ranges of sizes that I want to display in a ComboBox.

In Rage `C43:c47` I have the values like 100,200,300

In Range `D43:D47` I have an X.

In Range `E43:E47` I have values like 1000,1100,1200

I want to Concatenate the Values so it appears in the ComboBox like `100X1000`, `200X1100` or `300X1200`

**How can i do that?**

This is the code I used but of course it only shows one `Range`

`Me.SizeBox.List = Worksheets(1).Range("C43:C47").Value`

Comment: Does it have to be in vba? Could you have `=C43&D43&E43` in F43 etc?

Comment: @Alec is it a User_Form `ComboBox` or `ActiveX` ? is the name of the `ComboBox` "SizeBox" ?

Comment: It has to be ActiveX, it will appear on a UserForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub stitute()
Dim row As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = 3 'row that it finishes
col1 = 1 'Column with the first data
col2 = 2 'Column with the second data
col3 = 3 'Column with the third data

For row = 1 To lastrow 'Change the number to the starting row
    Me.SizeBox.AddItem Cells(row, col1).Value & Cells(row, col2).Value & Cells(row, col3).Value
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was trying to do. THANK YOU!